# Reading RSSI of a phone on a network with multiple access points

Tags: wireless, access-point

I have the following setup:

A wifi network with four access points on it (ubiquiti APs). When I connect my phone to the network, the phone gets assigned to one of the access points, lets say AP_A. I can read RSSI value between the phone and AP_A easily - not the problem. I also want to be able to read RSSI between the phone and other three access points (they are all on the same network) while the phone is connected to AP_A.

Is it possible? If so, I'd like some leads. Ubiquiti API documentation is non-existent / unhelpful.

Comment: I'm curious, did you find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after much research we came to a conclusion it is impossible (at least without spending ridiculous amount of resources) to make this work with Ubiquiti APs.